# Syntax issue with python dictionary and multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, python-multithreading

Hi I am trying to be able to start a thread from a dictionary entry using this code below. The rest of the code in the script is known good and fully functional. I cam gonna have to be able to choose from a bunch of different subroutines so I want to remove as much boilerplate as possible from the code. Thanks guys and gals!!!!

```
class worker_manager:

     i = test_imports()
     template('one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2);

     def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

     def generate(self, control_Queue, threadName, runNum):
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.template[threadName], args=(control_Queue, runNum))
         self.children[threadName] = p  
         p.start()    


      def terminate(self, threadName):
          self.children[threadName].join
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
  File "dynamicTest1.py", line 53
    template('one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2);
              ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone have any advice?

EDIT:
Here is how a normal thread works:

```
def generate(self, control_Queue, threadName, runNum):
        i = test_imports()
        if threadName == 'one':
            print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_Queue, runNum))
            self.children[threadName] = p
            p.start()
```

I wanna replace target in `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_Queue, runNum))` with a dictionary to remove the need for what was a MASSIVE amount of if/elif/else statements.

Comment: Well, it's not Python syntax, that's why ;-)  I don't know what you **intend** that line to do, but it's not legal syntax for anything.  If you're trying to pass a dict as an argument to the template function, then you need

`template({'one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2})`

Comment: I am trying to use a dictionary to store thread references

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you intend that line to do.  Is template supposed to be a function?  A dict?  Maybe that's it.  You're calling template as if it were a function.  If you want a dict named `template`, then


`template = {'one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2}`

Comment: Check it out the edit I just made

Comment: So you want template to be a dict.  In that case, what's wrong with the suggestion I made last time; i.e., do
`template = {'one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2}`

Comment: No you were right, I thought the issue wasnt in the dictionary but in how the variable was being referenced

Comment: OK!  `SyntaxError` is always raised at compile time, not at runtime.  So when you get a `SyntaxError`, you can be sure that your code hasn't been **run** at all - it didn't compile to begin with.

Comment: Thanks I am teaching myself python as I go so all these lessons are so great! Tim you da MAN!!!

Answer (score 1):

You do have a syntax error. Your template declaration should look like this:

```
template = {'one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2};
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
template = dict(one=i.import_1, two=i.import_2);
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is:

```
class worker_manager:

     i = test_imports()
     template = {'one': i.import_1, 'two': i.import_2}

 def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

     def generate(self, control_Queue, threadName, runNum):
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.template[threadName], args=(control_Queue, runNum))
         self.children[threadName] = p  
         p.start()    


     def terminate(self, threadName):
         self.children[threadName].join
```

It was just a syntax issue the code performs as advertised